# What directory should I use for "error: 'extra_PROGRAMS' is used but 'extradir' is undefined"?

Tags: autoconf, automake

I have a autoconf/automake system that has a stand-alone target called `stand`. I don't want `stand` to be normally built, so I have this in my Makefile.am:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = grace
extra_PROGRAMS = stand
...
stand_SOURCES = stand.cpp barry.cpp ...
```

This has worked for a while, but automake just got updated on my system and I'm now getting this error:

```
src/Makefile.am:4: error: 'extra_PROGRAMS' is used but 'extradir' is undefined
src/Makefile.am:66: warning: variable 'stand_SOURCES' is defined but no program or
src/Makefile.am:66: library has 'stand' as canonical name (possible typo)
```

So I added this:

```
extradir = .
```

But that has caused problems.

I don't want the `stand` program installed. It's just a test program for me. But it's not part of a formal test suite, it's just for my own purposes. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We found the bug!  It turns out that `extra` needs to be capitalized, like this:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = grace
EXTRA_PROGRAMS = stand
...
stand_SOURCES = stand.cpp barry.cpp ...
```

Comment: I did the same thing as you did. But I'm still getting the same error:  error: 'SHELLTESTS_PROGRAMS' is used but 'SHELLTESTSdir' is undefined. Here is a question I posted: [Check framework integration on project failed to build](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29718158/check-framework-integration-on-project-failed-to-build)

Answer (score 1):

You could try conditionally building it:

```
noinst_PROGRAMS=
if BUILD_STAND
noinst_PROGRAMS += stand
endif
stand_SOURCES = stand.cpp barry.cpp ...
```

This will not install it since it's in `noinst_PROGRAMS` and others will normally not build it since `BUILD_STAND` will normally not be defined for them.