# Check framework integration on project failed to build

Tags: autoconf, check-framework

I'm integrating C check framework for my project and I was able to run

`autoreconf --install`

successfully without any errors.

But when I integrate the C check framework, I'm getting an error and warnings that doesn't make sense.

Here is the error I'm getting

```
src/Makefile.am:7: warning: variable 'main_LDADD' is defined but no program or 
src/Makefile.am:7: library has 'main' as canonical name (possible typo)
tests/Makefile.am:2: error: 'SHELLTESTS_PROGRAMS' is used but 'SHELLTESTSdir' is undefined
tests/Makefile.am:3: warning:variable 'ShellTests_SOURCES' is defined but no program or
tests/Makefile.am:3: library has 'ShellTests' as canonical name (possible typo)  
tests/Makefile.am:5: warning: variable ShellTests_LDADD' is defined but no program or 
tests/Makefile.am:5:library has 'ShellTests' as canonical name (possible typo) 
                   autoreconf:automake failed with exit status: 1
```

I've followed the C check example source code, the difference between that and my project is that my class uses other class' methods.

Anyways, this is the Makefile.am under my tests/ that is causing 'havoc' on building the project

```
TESTS = shelltests
SHELLTESTS_PROGRAMS = shelltests

ShellTests_SOURCES = ShellTests.c $(top_builddir)/src/Shell.h $(top_builddir)/src/Parser.h $(top_builddir)/src/JobControl.h
ShellTests_CFLAGS = @CHECK_CFLAGS@
ShellTests_LDADD = $(top_builddir)/src/libshell.la @CHECK_LIBS@
```

This is the file structure for my project
src -
   Parser.h, Parser.c, Shell.h, Shell.c, Job.h, Job.c, Makefile.am
tests - 
   ShellTests.c Makefile.am

And this is the code in Makefile.am under src.

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libshell.la 
libshell_la_SOURCES = Shell.c Shell.h Parser.h Parser.c JobControl.h JobControl.c
bin_programs = main 
main_sources = Main.c  
main_LDADD = libshell.la
```

I followed this user's advice to see if it removes the error: [What directory should I use for "error: 'extra_PROGRAMS' is used but 'extradir' is undefined"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10702423/what-directory-should-i-use-for-error-extra-programs-is-used-but-extradir)
Alas, it does not.

I've tried building the example project - the one that you get when you download under examples, to see if I'm missing anything. But it's not able to build on my machine.

I'm on Mac OS X Mavericks (10.9)

- Autoconf 2.69
- Automake 1.15
- Libtool 2.4.6
- Check 0.9.14

Comment: update: I tried running the example directory to see if the project builds on my machine successfully (something I should have done, I just assumed it would work on any machine). And after adding the stuff that their examples build log tell me to do. I'm getting an error when I ran ./configure on my own project - this is without the check integration: configure: error: cannot find install-sh, install.sh, or shtool in "." "./.." "./../.." I'm sending a ticket to the c-check group.

Comment: It has been a while, but I seem to recall that letter case is distinct in an Automake file. For example, you typed `bin_programs` when it's supposed to be `bin_PROGRAMS`. Also, since you're building multiple tests, you'll likely want to use `check_PROGRAMS += shelltests` instead of `check_PROGRAMS = shelltests`, where `check` is the target name (e.g. `make check`). I'm not sure about the install-sh stuff. My guess is that the error about install-sh et al. is erroneous and results from the incorrect configuration. I've run into strange errors with the Autotools build system from that before.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune, I will try your suggestion. Unfortunately, I'm getting a build error about install-sh on their example, here's more info: [Check framework example giving me error when running './configure'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29738795/check-framework-example-giving-me-error-when-running-configure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a couple of things to build this project successfully. I first followed what I outlined here: [Check framework example giving me error when running './configure'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29738795/check-framework-example-giving-me-error-when-running-configure)

Then I followed c check frameworks' naming conventions for the tests source files.

Thanks for the help guys, it gave me some ideas on what the cause of compilation errors.