# Check framework example giving me error when running './configure'

Tags: autotools, configure, autoconf, automake, check-framework

I'm building the check framework example 'check_money', but it's not building on my machine. The error is:

```
configure: error: cannot find install-sh, install.sh, or shtool in "." "./.." "./../.."
```

I've tried installing it using:

```
libtoolize --force
aclocal
autoheader
automake --force-missing --add-missing
autoconf
./configure
```

It's still giving me the same error.

So, I copied the same directory to another directory and ran:

```
autoreconf --install
./configure
```

And it's still giving me the same error. I don't know what else to try.

I'm on Mac OS X Mavericks (10.9)

- Autoconf 2.69
- Automake 1.15
- Libtool 2.4.6
- Check 0.9.14

Comment: configure: error: cannot find install-sh, install.sh, or shtool in "." "./.." "./../.."

Comment: @mklement0, it's just a typo when I typed it here.

Comment: @macmania314 - its a good question now. It has a brief problem description, the exact error, and the things you have tried. Good luck with it. *If* you provide a link to the framework, I will try and build it on OS X 10.8.5.

Comment: @macmania314: Got it; however, it's always better to _copy & paste_ your _actual_ commands so as to rule out typos, which cause distractions like these.

Comment: Have a look through http://blog.gaku.net/autoconf/#summary to verify that you have done everything mentioned. I don't have OS X, but `glibtoolize` on OS X (just like `gmake` on FreeBSD) might be a source of problems. Even the `check` example builds a sample Libtool library `libmoney.la` in the `src` subdirectory, so it's worth checking.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune - I've followed this sample before, it still is giving me the same error :\ The weird thing is, it was able to build my own project before messing with their example. And now that I build, corrected the build errors on their example, my own project and their example fail to build... At least it's consistent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to figure out what was causing the errors - it was due to automake and libtools which I installed using brew install. Despite already installing autoconf which installed all the necessary tools I needed.

In addition, I looked at the configure script that autoconf created and I found that the variables wasn't being set-up properly which is why it was giving me the install-sh error because the $ac_dir wasn't assigned.

Here is what I did.

I uninstalled libtools and automake -

```
brew uninstall libtool automake
autoreconf -i
./configure
```

It ran with out any errors. I still don't know the reason why installing those 2 packages messed in building the project.